# VS Code Prettier extension replaces single quotation marks to double and removes backslash marks

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, prettier

I am working on an Angular project and I started to use VSCode recently. 
I am using the Prettier extension (version: 1.19.1) and it works fine, the only issue is it does not allow to write needed regular expressions. Prettier changes single quotation marks to double and removes backslash marks after save.

For example:

- `'^[a-zA-Z \-\']+'` becomes `"^[a-zA-Z -']+"`
- `/^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/` becomes `/^-?d+((.|,)d+)?$/`

VSCode extensions installed

- Angular Snippets (Version 9)
- Bracket Pair Colorizer
- PowerShell
- Prettier Code Formatter
- Code formatter seti-icons

I have followed many instructions such as adding `.prettierrc` file, changed configuration in `settings.json` file, but none of them were helpful.

This is my `.prettierrc.json` file:

```
{
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

This is `settings.json` file:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "vue-html": "html",
    "razor": "html",
    "plaintext": "jade"
 },
 "emmet.preferences": {
   "css.webkitProperties": "border-right,animation",
    "css.mozProperties": "",
   "css.oProperties": null,
   "css.msProperties": null
 },
 "[javascript]": {
   "editor.formatOnSave": true
 },
   "workbench.iconTheme": "seti"
 }
```

Here is `tslint.json` file:

```
rules : {
  ...
  "quotemark": [true, "single"],
  ...
}
```

`.editorconfig` file

```
  root = true

  [*]
  charset = utf-8
  indent_style = space
  indent_size = 2
  insert_final_newline = true
  trim_trailing_whitespace = true

  [*.md]
  max_line_length = off
  trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem on [Prettier's playground](https://prettier.io/playground)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=double+quote+visual+studio
There are vs screenshots and explanations. I underline the question has been already asked.

You have to write \\ for the editor to leave one and according to this answer 4 for two:
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2789

I hope it helps !